# How to use SUM and MAX in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to give the name of the product that has been sold the most overall with its sales quantity. Total Quantity is the sum of products sold - that are the products whose order status (order_status) is Paid or Shipped.
I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
product_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
product_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
product_price numeric NOT NULL,
product_type product_types NOT NULL,
product_created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()


CREATE TABLE orders (
order_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
order_store_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES stores,
order_user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
order_status order_states NOT NULL,
order_created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()

CREATE TABLE order_items (
order_id INT references orders,
product_id INT references products,
quantity INT DEFAULT 1 CHECK ( quantity > 0 ),
PRIMARY KEY (order_id, product_id)
```

I have written the query:

```
SELECT products.product_name, maxam
  FROM  products, (SELECT SUM(quantity) AS total FROM order_items) AS foo
  WHERE orders.order_id = order_items.order_id AND orders.order_status IN ('Paid', 'Shipped')
  GROUP BY orders.order_status
  HAVING maxam = MAX(total)
```

, but I think there are a lot of mistakes (working with sql for the first time)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: What's your dbms? could your provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I am using postgresql and the output should be just one row withh the name of the product and it's quantity(it must be the maximum of sum's of the quantities for each product)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT top 1 products.product_name,  SUM(quantity) as QTY
  FROM  
orders inner join
order_items
on orders.order_id = order_items.order_id 

order_items inner join
products
on order_items.product_id  = products.product_id 

WHERE orders.order_status IN ('Paid', 'Shipped')
  GROUP BY products.product_name
 order by qty desc
```

Comment: This is the correct answer ? HOW ? PostgreSQL  does not have TOP 1 and you said "I am using postgresql" ??

Comment: Yes, it works, but i was trying to use the max-fucntion, because i am not sure how top works. Is it the same as max?

Comment: Hi @PDP I repeat - top does not work for PostgreSQL  ! How it can be correct answer ? Also, The joins are not correctly done here in this example .... I just started to write my comment to this answer to say what error it has and then I see it is correct ??

Comment: Yes, I use Postgre. I did not express myself correctly, the idea is correct, but there were mistakes that I corrected and it works, but I'm not sure where exactly to use the max function, because I think max(sum(...)) is not allowed.

Comment: I think that i can use LIMIT 1 after ORDER BY

Comment: Hi @PDP so ? How is this correct answer ?

Comment: To declare an answer as correct that has nothing to with the question is really interesting. The question was how to use max and this is not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Working query:

```
SELECT products.product_name , SUM(quantity) AS QTY 
  FROM orders JOIN  order_items ON orders.order_id = order_items.order_id JOIN products ON order_items.product_id  = products.product_id  
  WHERE order_status IN ('Paid', 'Shipped')
  GROUP BY products.product_name
  ORDER BY QTY desc LIMIT 1;
```